# Google Kickstart 2016 round A

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm pretty new to programming but I managed to write a program to solve problem " Country leader" in Google Kickstart 2016 round A

https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000201ca2/0000000000201d30

My program worked well in my IDE, but when I pasted it into Kickstart, it ran into RE( Runtime error).
I've searched on Google but I could hardly find an effective solution to this problem.
I will really appreciate if somebody can explain to me why this error occurred.
Here is my code:

```
t = int(input())
tc = 0
while t > 0:
    name_number = int(input())
    name_dict = {}
    for _ in range(name_number):
        name = input()
        name_dict[name] = list(dict.fromkeys(list(name.replace(" ",""))))
        name = ""
    leader_list = []
    for a in list(name_dict):
        if all(len(name_dict[a]) >= len(name_dict[i]) for i in (list(name_dict))):
            leader_list.append(a)
    if len(leader_list) > 1:
        for x in leader_list:
            if all( x <= y for y in leader_list):
                leader = x
                break
    else:
        leader = leader_list[0]
    tc += 1
    print(f"Case #{tc}: {leader}")
    t -= 1
```

Comment: Did you try using "Show test input" and using the test examples and "Run test"?  This could help you find out if the issue is with some test case you didn't consider or if the same test case works on your computer but not on google's environment.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I did so but it also resulted in a runtime error.

Comment: However when I changed the line print(f"Case #{tc}: {leader}") into print("Case #" + str(tc) +":", str(leader)) it turned out to pass all the sets in Google Kickstart. Now I'm being confused why there was such a difference.

Comment: formatting strings with `f` is pretty new, added in python 3.6 (2016): https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html  From the `Platform` section of the Google FAQs, we can see that their python3 is `3.5`: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/faq

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to keep any list to store the sorted names. You can use a dictionary which stores person name as key and the length of distinct characters as value. Sort the dictionary by value in descending order and then by key in ascending order. The first sorted key is the desired name as `leader`.

I have implemented this logic like following and it passed all test cases of the challenge:

```
cas = int(input())
for t in range(1, cas+1):
    n = int(input())

    d = {}
    for i in range(n):
        person = input()
        d[person] = len(set(person.replace(" ","")))

    for key, value in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])):
        print("Case #{}: {}".format(t, key))
        break
```

Explanation:

`key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))` this sort the dictionary by value in descending order and key in ascending order. The first value after this sort operation is our desired output and thus I break the loop. As prior to Python 3.6, dictinoary could not be sorted and I do not know which Python version `codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com` uses. So, I used a loop to print sorted dictionary value and break the loop after the first print.

For your kind reference, I have selected Python 3 from language dropdown and pasted the above code in the editor. It passed all testcases.

Answer (score 0):

At the time you posted this, Kick Start used python 3.5, which does not support f-strings. However, now their python3 version is version 3.7, so your code should now work.